# C# Winium List Items into array

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I'm using Winium, with Selenium Remote and C#, and I need to store in array the contents of listbox:

```
App = Inetcpl.cpl (internet settings),  //list of sites in Trusted sites
```

But doesn't work, any suggestions?

Thanks!

My code:

```
IList<IWebElement> options = driver.FindElements(By.Name(Sites:));
foreach (IWebElement option in options)
{
    Console.WriteLine(option.Text);
}
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp